# Using UILabel as a UITextField, will Apple have an issue upon submission?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UILabel that acts much like a UITextField. The UITextField's frame is off the screen, it becomes firstResponder and whatever you type in it is shown on the UILabel. I did this at the time to format for currency and because the UITextField is used for a lot of different labels in the UIView. It's my first iOS app so there is still a lot of learning going on.

I know this is not a great design decision, but at this point it is so highly coupled to many processes it would take a lot of work to replace the UILabel with the UITextField.

My question - **in your own experience(s), would Apple reject a submission because of something like this?** I know they are big on a consistent UX (i.e. in UITextField you can hold down for the magnifying glass, and you can't here).

I know only Apple can say for sure when I submit it, but I am more gauging if I can get by with this or if I need to spend time on a rewrite.

Comment: My personal opinion is that there is nothing wrong with what you are going - you are not using private APIs or "perverting" some Apple UIView subclass. I cannot think of any reason that this in and of itself would cause you trouble. I should add I have over a dozen apps that have been approved by Apple.

Comment: I think that's pretty smart what you are doing. Nice trick. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is almost no way that apple would reject something like this - Apple is always looking for great ways to be creative and think outside the box, what your doing is just that!

Directly from apple:

[image: Be creative!]

Again, Apple will never reject creative or innovative apps.